# mount /var/log in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to persist all of my container's /var/log/ so that I can keep the Apache logs once the container exits.

I have this in my compose file:

```
volumes:
      - ../logs/apache/:/var/log/
```

but when I try and bring the container up I get an error:

```
ModSecurity: Failed to open the audit log file: /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
```

which indicates to me that the mount is overwriting the /var/log and so nothing is there. How do I fix this so that anything created/written to /var/log inside the container is then mounted outside so that it persists. Thanks

Comment: would you have the same problem if you use '- /tmp/:/var/log/'
my point being, if something has opened it on your host, then writing may not be allowed.